# From which class of continuous distributions on $(0,\infty )$ is $F(t) = 1 - (1 + \frac t 2 )e^{-t}$?

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request

I encountered the distribution given by the cumulative distribution function

$$F(t) = 1 - (1 + \frac t 2 )e^{-t} = 1 - e^{-t} - \frac t 2 e^{-t},\quad \quad t\geq 0$$

By differentiation the probabiltiy density function $f$ would be
$$f(t) = \frac{1+t} 2 e^{-t},\quad \quad t\geq 0$$

The structure looks so simple that I first thought I would find it among [the list of Continuous distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Continuous_distributions) of Wikipedia, but I could not find any distribution from the list, which has this as special case.

I look for a class or name of this type of distribution. Technically, this is a mixture between the exponential distribution and the gamma distribution with shape $2$ and thus does not need to have a name.

Comment: "Mixture between exponential and gamma" is a good description. If you note that the exponential distribution itself is a gamma distribution, then you can call this part of the class of "mixtures of gamma distributions." I'm not sure how common/useful this characterization is.

Comment: I also think that mixture of gamma is a good description. But I hoped that it has a more specialized one, e.g. a form with specification of parameters and so on. Mixture of gamma is not really useful for my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y\sim f_Y$ with
$$
f_Y(y)=\tfrac{1+y}{2}e^{-y},\quad y\geq 0.
$$
One way you could relate the density $f_Y$ to known densities is by defining $Y$ as a function of a known random variable. For instance, let $X\sim\operatorname{Gamma}(2,1)$ and $Z=X|X\geq 1$, then
$$
f_Z(z)=\frac{ze^{-z}}{\int_1^\infty te^{-t}\,\mathrm dt}=\frac{ze^{-z}}{2/e},\quad z\geq 1.
$$
Now define $Y=Z-1$. It follows that $f_Y(y)=f_Z(1+y)=\frac{1+y}{2}e^{-y},\quad y\geq 0$, which is your pdf.

> Thus, $f_Y$ is the density of
> $$
> Y=(X|X\geq 1)-1,\quad X\sim\operatorname{Gamma}(2,1).
> $$

Comment: This is indeed a very good observation. This suits the way I encountered this distribtion.